# How to differentiate the file is invalid when using MediaMetadataRetriever?

Tags: android

I want to get the duration of media file.

I use `MediaMetadataRetriever` to get the duration of media file like the following code.

```
File file = new File(viewTag.mFileNode.mName) ;
                    String tempfilePath = file.getPath();
                    MediaMetadataRetriever fileDuration = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

                    fileDuration.setDataSource(tempfilePath);

                    duration = fileDuration.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                    Log.i(TAG, "duration = " + duration);

                    Long VideoDuration = Long.parseLong(duration);
                    Long minius = (VideoDuration/1000)/60;
                    Long seconds = (VideoDuration/1000) % 60;

                    viewTag.mTime.setText(String.valueOf(minius) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds)) ;
```

It working when the media file is normal , but it crash at `fileDuration.setDataSource(tempfilePath);` when the media file is damage.

**How to avoid the crash when the media file is damage ?**

The idea of mine is :

```
If(the media is normal){

    //Use MediaMetadataRetriever to get the duration of file 

}else if(the media file is damage) {

    //doesn't Use MediaMetadataRetriever to get the duration of file 

}
```

**How to differentiate the file is damage when using MediaMetadataRetriever ?**

or **Does there has other method to get the duration of media file ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the following approach:

```
File file = new File(viewTag.mFileNode.mName) ;
String tempfilePath = file.getPath();
MediaMetadataRetriever fileDuration = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

try {
    fileDuration.setDataSource(tempfilePath);

    duration = fileDuration.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    Log.i(TAG, "duration = " + duration);

    Long VideoDuration = Long.parseLong(duration);
    Long minius = (VideoDuration/1000)/60;
    Long seconds = (VideoDuration/1000) % 60;

    viewTag.mTime.setText(String.valueOf(minius) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds)) ;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // the file must be corrupt, do something else...
} finally {
    // call release when you are done!
    fileDuration.release();
}
```

[FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) also works well with corrupt files. You can try that library also.

Comment: This library uses FFmpeg, which handles corrupt files better. Can you accept this answer if it solved your problem?